# Проблемы с import в node js

Tags: node.js

Как пофиксить это:

```
C:\ndtest>node text.js
    (node:5388) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
    (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
    C:\ndtest\text.js:2
    import chalk from 'chalk'
    ^^^^^^
    
    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
        at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:992:16)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:27)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:941:32)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:782:14)
        at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
        at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Comment: Используйте `require` вместо `import`

Comment: либо https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node-js